# Does robot_localization merge RPY and Quaternion Orientation?

Tags: imu, navigation, robot-localization

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I was wondering whether robot_localization package merges RPY and quaternion orientation data for you (from 2 different sensors), or whether this needs to be done manually prior to sending it to the package?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/234531/does-robot_localization-merge-rpy-and-quaternion-orientation?/) by [bzhan](https://answers.ros.org/users/26225/bzhan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2016-05-17

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The EKF and UKF in `r_l` take in the message types described [here](http://wiki.ros.org/robot_localization#Features). All the message types that have orientation data use quaternions. `r_l` doesn't support messages with RPY data, so if you only have that, you'll have to convert it.

---

Originally posted by [Tom Moore](https://answers.ros.org/users/3384/tom-moore/) with karma: 13689 on 2016-05-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0